# Mongodb 5 node driver detailed schema validation error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Using mongodb 5 improved json schema validation errors (https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/mongodb-5-0-schema-validation/), we should be able to have a detailed validation error when e.g inserting incorrect data in a document.
However, it does not seem to be working using latest mongodb node driver 4.2.

Here's the error I have :

```
MongoServerError: BSON field 'insert.documents.0' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object'
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:741:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (domain.js:470:12)
    at processIncomingData (/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:167:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/workspace/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:64:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Socket.emit (domain.js:470:12) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 14,
  codeName: 'TypeMismatch'
```

Is there a way to have the detailed error message ?

Comment: Do you have an update on this issue, because I can't seem to find any sort of information about this...

Comment: It is hard to answer your question without a sample code showing schema definition, and the insert statement. If you are using `model.create()`, you will see improved validation error. However, I couldn't get it for `model.insertMany()`.

Comment: I have asked a similar question here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72886575/does-mongoose-model-insertmany-support-the-improved-schema-validation-errors-w