# Does mongoose model.insertMany() support the improved schema validation errors with mongodb 5

Tags: mongoose

As stated [here](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-5-0-schema-validation/), I could see the improved schema validation errors for `model.create()` but not for `model.insertMany()`. The error format for `model.insertMany()` is still the following. Does `insertMany` not support improved format yet?

Env:

```
mongodb 5.0.6
mongoose 6.2.4
node v16.14.1
```

Schema:

```
{
  "$jsonSchema": {
    "bsonType": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "required": [
      "name"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "_id": {
        "bsonType": "objectId"
      },
      "name": {
        "bsonType": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Script that throws the following error:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log('error: ', JSON.stringify(err, null, 4));
  process.exit(1);
});

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/t12");

  const schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String, value: String });
  const model = mongoose.model("tests", schema);

  let res;
  res = await model.insertMany([{value: 'hello'}], { rawResult: true, ordered: false });
  console.log('insert: ', res);
  process.exit(0);
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "code": 121,
    "writeErrors": [
        {
            "code": 121,
            "index": 0,
            "errmsg": "Document failed validation",
            "op": {
                "value": "hello",
                "_id": "62c5ae93986f65769edc60e7",
                "__v": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "result": {
        "ok": 1,
        "writeErrors": [
            {
                "code": 121,
                "index": 0,
                "errmsg": "Document failed validation",
                "op": {
                    "value": "hello",
                    "_id": "62c5ae93986f65769edc60e7",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            }
        ],
        "writeConcernErrors": [],
        "insertedIds": [
            {
                "index": 0,
                "_id": "62c5ae93986f65769edc60e7"
            }
        ],
        "nInserted": 0,
        "nUpserted": 0,
        "nMatched": 0,
        "nModified": 0,
        "nRemoved": 0,
        "upserted": []
    },
    "insertedDocs": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoose passes the error received from the node.js mongodb driver. Following code shows how to find the schema validation error from the `err.writeErrors` property.

Code:

```
main().catch((err) => {
  // console.log('error: ', JSON.stringify(err, null, 4)); // -> this doesn't show errInfo where the schema validation errors are
  console.log('error: ',JSON.stringify(err.writeErrors[0].errInfo,null,4));
  process.exit(1);
});

async function main() {
  const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

  const schema = {
    $jsonSchema: {
      bsonType: "object",
      additionalProperties: false,
      required: ["name"],
      properties: {
        _id: {
          bsonType: "objectId",
        },
        name: {
          bsonType: "string",
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const client = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27020", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  });
  const db = client.db("t12");
  await db.dropCollection("tests");
  await db.createCollection("tests", { validator: schema });

  await db.collection("tests").insertMany([{ value: "t2" }]); // should fail
  await client.close();
}
```

Error:

```
error:  {
    "failingDocumentId": "62c64fcade43d36b7ebb3e58",
    "details": {
        "operatorName": "$jsonSchema",
        "schemaRulesNotSatisfied": [
            {
                "operatorName": "additionalProperties",
                "specifiedAs": {
                    "additionalProperties": false
                },
                "additionalProperties": [
                    "value"
                ]
            },
            {
                "operatorName": "required",
                "specifiedAs": {
                    "required": [
                        "name"
                    ]
                },
                "missingProperties": [
                    "name"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people facing similar issues, you need to check what your `featureCompatibilityVersion`, if it's anything below `5.0` then you're not going to get any of those detailed error reports. Would've been nice if MongoDB mentioned that somewhere in their docs or announcement article...

1. Open `mongosh` and write:

```js
db.adminCommand({ getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 })
// "4.4"
```

2. Update `featureCompatibilityVersion` to `5.0`

```js
db.adminCommand({ setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "5.0" })
```

3. Restart `mongod`.